# How do I extract a value returned by reference (via JNA)?

Tags: java, jna

I'm trying to call a 3rd-party C library (DLL) function using JNA 4.1.0.

The C function declaration is:

```
int hasp_get_sessioninfo(
    long handle,
    const char *format,
    char **info);
```

My JNA direct mapping method looks like this:

```
public static native int hasp_get_sessioninfo(
    NativeLong sessionHandle,
    String query,
    PointerByReference info);
```

The C function takes an out-argument `info`. `info` gets allocated by the C function, and then filled with a NULL-terminated string.

In Java part, after I invoke the Java method, I try to read a `String` from the `PointerByReference info` like so:

```
public String getInfo(final String format) throws SentinelException {
    PointerByReference buffer = new PointerByReference();
    int status = SentinelLibrary.hasp_get_sessioninfo(handle.getValue(), format, buffer);
    if (status != 0) {
        throw new SentinelException();
    }
    String info = buffer.getPointer().getString(0);
    SentinelLibrary.hasp_free(buffer.getPointer());
    return info;
}
```

The problem is that I always get some random value of eight to twelve or so bytes. It leads me to believe that the `buffer` wasn't at all touched by the C function.

Is there something wrong with my JNA mapping? Can I debug this better, to see what's going on inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PointerByReference.getValue()` will provide you the "returned" value.  `PointerByReference.getPointer()` gives you the address that was passed to the native function.

Comment: That's it. Thank you. Do I have to worry about the now unreferenced pointer I get by calling `getPointer()` i.e. does it get freed when `PointerByReference` is GCed?

Comment: JNA will deallocate the storage when the `PointerByReference` object gets GC'd.  `getPointer()` doesn't allocate anything; the memory is allocated when the `PointerByReference` object is created.